# Dns.GetHostEntry returns local host name not name known to DNS

Tags: c#, powershell, dns, windows-server-2012

On a new Windows 2012 server [Dns.GetHostEntry Method (IPAddress)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143997.aspx) returns the locally specified host name but not the name known to DNS for the IP address. The IP address is the new server's.

Running nslookup on the same IP returns the correct DNS name for the server.

Likewise running `GetHostEntry()` for 127.0.0.1 returns the local host name instead of "localhost". I don't know if this is related.

I thought `GetHostEntry()` is supposed to return the name as specified in DNS. Why does it return the locally-defined host name when supplied with the local IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Is your server a domain controler ?

On My DC it gives the dns name :

```
PS C:\> [system.net.dns]::GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1")

HostName                                                Aliases                                                 AddressList                                           
--------                                                -------                                                 -----------                                           
VMESS01.SILOGIX-ESS01.local                             {}                                                      {fe80::7535:fadb:225a:4a2a%12, 88.191.232.219, 2002...
```

Comment: The server is no domain controller. Maybe your DC's host name is the same as its DNS name?

Comment: As far as I understand if a computer is inside a domain, it's always the case. In fact your server is not inside a domain ?

Comment: I believe the server in question was in a domain. Why would domain membership affect whether GetHostEntry() does what is advertised or not?